# How to avoid people deleting games on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

Seems like anyone can just start the Xbox and delete games. Setting up a guest account helped on not letting anyone just create new accounts, but anyone can still delete games. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, you can change your sign options so the password is needed for almost everything in the Xbox.

https://beta.support.xbox.com/help/account-profile/signin-security/change-signin-preferences